# How many Fourier coefficients of a sparse signal $f=\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n\delta_{t_n}$ are needed to determine $f$ uniquely?

Tags: fourier-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, signal-analysis

Let $N \in \mathbb N$ and $c_n \in \mathbb C$, $t_n \in \mathbb R$ for $n=1, \dots, N$. Suppose that $f$ is a linear combination of dirac-deltas with locations $t_n$ and coefficients $c_n$, i.e.

$$
f=\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n\delta_{t_n}.
$$

The $k$-th Fourier coefficient of $f$ is defined by

$$
\hat f (k) = \sum_{n=1}^Nc_ne^{-2\pi i k t_n}
$$

How many Fourier coefficients $\hat f(k)$ do we need such that $f$ is uniquely determined by them? In other words: For which (minimal) $K \subset \mathbb Z$ such that
$$
\hat f(k) = \hat h (k) \ \forall k \in K
$$
is $f=h$ where $h=\sum_{n=1}^Nd_n\delta_{s_n}$ is a second linear combination of deltas.

Comment: Are $t_n$ and $s_n$ in $[0,1)$ or similarly restricted? Otherwise $f$ is never uniquely determined so you can shift by $1$.

Comment: Perhaps Theorem 1.3 of the following paper could be of use: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409186.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you only care about $t_n, s_n$ mod $1$, then $2N$ values of $k$ suffice. (A dimension argument shows this is optimal). In fact, we can take $K= \{0,\dots, 2N-1\}$.

Form a $2N \times N$ matrix whose entry in the $j$th column and the $k+1$st rown is $e^{-  2 \pi i  k t_j}$. Add at most $N$ additional column to the matrix of the form $e^{ -2 \pi i k s_j}$, but don't add an additional if $s_j$ already equals $t_i$ for some $i$.

Because the Vandermonde matrix is invertible, this matrix is injective. We can see that $\hat{f}(k)$ for $k$ from $0$ to $2N-1$ is the transform of the vector $( c_1, c_2,\dots, c_N, 0,\dots, 0)$ under this matrix, and similarly $\hat{h}(k)$ for $k$ from $0$ to $2N-1$ is the transform of a vector with entries $d_1,\dots, d_N$.

Because the matrix is injective, if $\hat{f}(k) = \hat{h}(k)$ for all such $k$, then these two vectors are equal, so the coefficients of each delta function in $f$ and $h$ are equal, and thus $f=h$.

For a robust version of this, you will need to look at the reference Shil B. posted.

Comment: Just a small additional question: Does this also work if I replace $K$ by a set of the form $\tilde K = \{ a, \dots, a+2N-1 \}$ where $a$ is some integer?

Comment: @Muzi Yes, in that case the matrix is obtained from this one by multiplying on the right by a diagonal matrix (with nonzero entries $e^{ - 2\pi i a t_j}$) and thus remains injective.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I kind of expected that one needs more Fourier coefficients since the $c_j$'s are complex ... but this seems not to be the case